# How to pronounce education?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, connected-speech, assimilation-linguistics

Well, Oxford, Cambridge and Macmillan lists /ˌɛ**dj**ʊˈkeɪʃ(ə)n/, /ˌe**d.j**ʊˈkeɪ.ʃən/, and /ˌe**dj**ʊˈkeɪʃ(ə)n/ respectively as the pronunciation for education. Yet, people say /e**dʒ**ʊkeɪʃən/.

Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @snailboat see http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/education and listen to the pronunciation

Comment: Which version of English do you want to master?  British English? Indian English? American English? Canadian English? Something else?

Comment: @Jasper how is that relevant ? I prefer brit english

Comment: Some words are pronounced differently in different varieties of English.  A word that you know has multiple pronunciations is especially likely to have regional or dialectal differences in pronunciation.  Sometimes (like with the ancient Hebrew word *shibboleth*) the difference matters.  And if you want to speak British English, we should encourage native speakers of British English to answer your question.

Comment: Exactly. If you are in the UK, you ask for a to-MAH-to. If in America, you want a to-MAY-to. In the UK, the letter Z is "zed." In America, it's "zee."

Comment: @A.Beth My favorite: *schedule* reads /ˈskeˌdʒul/ in AmE, but /ˈʃedjuːl/ in BrE.

Comment: @MAKZ When it's possible, try to listen to native speakers of various dialects carefully. It could be fun! Even such a simple word as *oil*, which is supposed to be pronounced as /ɔɪl/ in both AmE and BrE, never sounds the same to my ear when I listen to the two dialects carefully. ;-)

Comment: @Jasper et al. There are some processes that we go theough which mean that the pronunciation of a word is not nearly the same all the time (of course, if you think about it, no two pronunciations of a word will ever be the same). For example, any speaker might use a glottal stop at the end of a word in a sentence - but if they say the sentence again (i.e. by accident in recorded speech), say it differently the next time. Yod-coalescence is a bit like this. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't :)

Comment: @A.Beth Only a few guys has read carefully what i asked. My point s IPA says d sound is retained, but virtually all speakers drop the d sound and say eh.joo.kei.shn. then i asked Why.

Comment: The British sometimes say /dʒuk/ and not /djuk/. Of course they'll say /ɛdʒʊˈkeɪʃ(ə)n/ sometimes. But not all speakers of British English do this. Are you sure you're able to distinguish a slightly palatalized /dj/ from a /dʒ/?

Comment: personally, BrE, in my head I say ed-yoo, but most people would perceive a slight slur towards ej-u. Life's like that.

Answer (score 4):

/ɛdʒuˈkɛɪʃən/ is the way it's pronounced in General American (the standard American accent), and /edjuˈkɛɪʃən/ is the way it's pronounced in Recieved Pronunciation (the standard British accent). I'm not entirely sure (since I'm a GA speaker), but I wouldn't be surprised if RP speakers sometimes pronounce it /ɛdʒuˈkɛɪʃən/ when they're not being particularly careful about their speech.

This is due to two processes called [yod-dropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-dropping) and [yod-coalescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-coalescence). Yod-dropping causes /j/ in historic /ju/ to be dropped in certain situations. In GA, this happens after any of the coronal consonants (consonants articulated with the tip of the tongue): /t/, /d/, /s/, /z/, /ʃ/ /θ/, /tʃ/, /dʒ/ /l/, /ɹ/, and possibly /ʒ/ and /ð/ (I can't find any examples of yod-dropping after /ʒ/ and /ð/, but they are coronal consonants). In RP, however, /j/ is never dropped after /n/, and it is only sometimes dropped after /t/, /d/, /s/, /z/, /θ/, and /l/ (theoretically, it would also sometimes be retained after /ð/). Yod-coalescence turns /tj/, /dj/, /sj/, and /zj/ into /tʃ/, /dʒ/, /ʃ/, and /ʒ/ in unstressed syllables in GA and sometimes RP.

So, due to yod-dropping, "new" is pronounced /nju/ in RP, but /nu/ in GA; "Zeus" (a god in Greek mythology) is pronounced /zjus/ in RP, but /zus/ in GA (yod-coalescence doesn't occur here because the syllable is stressed); "due" is /dju/ in RP, but /du/ in GA; and "enthusiasm" is pronounced /ɛnˈθjuzi.æz(ə)m/ in RP, but /ɛnˈθuzi.æz(ə)m/ in GA. Due to yod-coalescence, "nature", historically pronounced /ˈnɛɪtjuɹ/, is now pronounced /ˈnɛɪtʃə/ in RP and /ˈnɛɪtʃɚ/ in GA; "azure", historically pronounced /ˈæzjuɹ/, is now pronounced /ˈæʒ(j)ə/ in RP and /ˈæʒɚ/ in GA; "educate", historically pronounced /ˈɛdjukɛɪ̯t/, is now pronounced /ˈɛdjʊkɛɪ̯t/ or /ˈɛdʒəkɛɪ̯t/ in RP and /ˈɛdʒəkɛɪ̯t/ in GA.

Comment: It's pronounced /edʒu-/ by the vast majority of BE speakers:) By the queen, in particular! I don't understand something in your post :( If the yod's dropped, how does it coalesce?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that none of my examples included yod-coalescence, only yod-dropping. I'll edit that. I didn't realize it before, but yeah, there's no yod-dropping in yod-coalescence because the yod isn't dropped, it merges with the preceding sound to form a new one. The education example is just yod-coalesence, but I still think it's good to mention yod-dropping because it's closely related to yod-coalesence (and for anyone who doesn't know, "yod" refers /j/ sound).

Answer (score 0):

An interesting problem. I'm no native English speaker (German) and used to the pronunciation (Pn) of the word education  with /dj/. Made curious by the question I had a look at some dictionaries:

OALD BrE ʤ, AmE ʤ

Collins only one Pn: dj - no differentiation between BrE and AmE

Macmillan only one Pn: dj

Cambridge BrE dj, AmE ʤ

This clearly shows how careless and imprecise renowned dictionaries are as to Pn.
No dictionary gives a hint that the Pn of education is an example of language change. /dj/ is in the process of changing to /ʤ/. In AmE ʤ seems to be the standard Pn, in BrE you can hear the traditional dj and the more recent ʤ.

The only dictionary that really indicates the problem of two Pn-s for BrE is my old
Everyman's English Pronouncing Dictionary by Daniel Jones and A.C.Gimson. Only for BrE. It gives as first Pn dj and as second Pn ʤ. (I have the 14th edition from 1977.)